# Size of image increases after cropping

Tags: c#

I have c# code to crop images.

When i crop image (size:191 KB, using my c# code) then size of resulted (cropped) image increases (size:2.44 MB)

Please tell me why size increases after cropping ..???

```
 Bitmap source = new Bitmap(@"F:\images\Row" + i + "Col" + j + ".jpg");
                Rectangle section = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(1362, 761));
                Bitmap CroppedImage = CropImage(source, section);
                CroppedImage.Save(@"file path\Row" + i + "Col" + j + ".jpg");



    public Bitmap CropImage(Bitmap source, Rectangle section)
    {
        // An empty bitmap which will hold the cropped image
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(section.Width, section.Height);

        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        // Draw the given area (section) of the source image
        // at location 0,0 on the empty bitmap (bmp)
        g.DrawImage(source, 0, 0, section, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        return bmp;
    }
```

Comment: Please, show us your code and remove extra question marks

Comment: What is the format of the original file and the saved file?

Comment: Write your code into your question, not as a comment..

Comment: @Rafay : Try saving your `source` and see if the size increase for the original image. I suspect Bitmap has lower compression that .jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Telepathic power: you are talking about size of file on disk and comparing original compressed file (likely JPG) with cropped version saved in non-compressed format (likely BMP).

Fix: save cropped image in compressed format.

[Image.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9t4syfhh.aspx) with 2 arguments lets you specify format (i.e. unlike one argument version you use in your sample).

Example from the article:

```
// Construct a bitmap from the button image resource.
Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(typeof(Button), "Button.bmp");

// Save the image as a GIF.
bmp1.Save("c:\\button.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

Comment: @Rafay I've updated the answer with MSDN link and sample code from the article.

Comment: Size of image reduce to 440 KB from 2.44 MB. Is there any way to reduce size of image to 100 KB or less ?